# Jenkins Pipeline - build same job multiple times in parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a pipeline in Jenkins which triggers same job multiple times in different node(agents).

I have "Create_Invoice" job Jenkins, configured : (Execute Concurrent builds if necessary)
If I click on Build 10 times it will run 10 times in different (available) agents/nodes.

Instead of me clicking 10 times, I want to create a parallel pipeline.

I created something like below - it triggers the job but only once.
What Am I missing or is it even possible to trigger same test more than once at the same time from pipeline?

Thank you in advance

```
node {
    def notifyBuild = { String buildStatus ->
        // build status of null means successful
        buildStatus =  buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESSFUL'
        // Default values
 def tasks = [:]
    try { 
tasks["Test-1"] = {  
    stage ("Test-1") {
        b = build(job: "Create_Invoice",  propagate: false).result       
   }
 }  
tasks["Test-2"] = {    
   stage ("Test-2") {
        b = build(job: "Create_Invoice",  propagate: false).result
        }
}    
 parallel tasks   
       } catch (e) {
        // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
        currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
        throw e
    }
      finally {
          notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: You want to run the job 10 times in the same agent or 10 times in each agent?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by passing different parameters to the same job. You should add parameters to your build steps, although you obviously don't need them. For example, I added a string parameter.

```
tasks["Test-1"] = {  
  stage ("Test-1") {
    b = build(job: "Create_Invoice",  parameters: [string(name: "PARAM", value: "1")], propagate: false).result       
  }
}  
tasks["Test-2"] = {    
  stage ("Test-2") {
    b = build(job: "Create_Invoice", parameters: [string(name: "PARAM", value: "2")], propagate: false).result
  }
}
```

As long as the same parameters or no parameters are passed to the same job, the job is only tirggered once.

See also this Jenkins issue, it describes the same problem:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55748

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to switch to Declarative pipeline instead of Scripted pipeline.

Declarative pipeline has parallel stages support which is your goal:

https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: Thank you!! Got side tracked with other project and have not tried it yet but will update the result in few days

Answer (score 0):

This example will grab the available agent from the Jenkins and iterate and run the pipeline in all the active agents.

with this approach, you no need to invoke this job from an upstream job many time to build on a different agent. This Job itself will manage everything and run all the stages define in all the online node.

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers.each { c ->
    
    if(c.node.toComputer().online) {
        node(c.node.labelString) {
            stage('steps-one') {
                echo "Hello from Steps One"
            }
            stage('stage-two') {
                echo "Hello from Steps Two"
            }
        }
    } else {
        println "SKIP ${c.node.labelString} Because the status is : ${c.node.toComputer().online} "
    }
    
}
```